# Problem when trying to style buttons and anchors alike

Tags: html, css, browser

The HTML page shown below has four "buttons". Two of them are real button tags, but two are actually anchors (I deliberately left the underlining in their style so you can tell them apart). The goal was to style them using a  `btn` class in a way that they look the same and align next to each other in a "button bar". But when you load the page in a browser, you will notice two differences between the buttons and the anchors - the buttons have a vertical offset, and their content is centered vertically. However, they use the same style class, and even when I compared the computed styles with browser developer tools, I could find no difference.

So why does this happen? I already found that not setting `overflow` and the `height` and instead adjusting it via `padding` and `font-size` can be used as a workaround. So it seems to have something to do with setting the height. But why do you get such an effect when you set it? And changing the `overflow` property strangely reverses the offset effect. I considered it might have to do with the `box-sizing` property which seems to be different for anchors and buttons, and could cause the height to be interpreted differently - but since there are no paddings and margins, it should not make a difference, it would also not alter the offset, and setting the `box-sizing` property manually for the class did not change the effect either.

Again, I'm not primiarly looking for a fix here, much less a discussion whether it's a good idea to style buttons and anchors the same, but I'm interested in a solid explanation of this CSS phenomenon. Is it a browser quirk with styling buttons? But then why do all the browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE) show the same effect? Or did I overlook something obvious?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<style>

.btn {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
    height: 2em;
    width: 10em;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

</style>

</head><body>

<button type="submit" class="btn">
    Button
</button><a href="#" class="btn">
    Button
</a><button type="button" class="btn">
    Button
</button><a href="#" class="btn">
    Button
</a>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a button that has not been styled looks different than an anchor that hasn't been styled, if you apply the same style to both, there will be a difference. I think the only solution is to just apply different classes to the buttons, and to the anchors.

Comment: But if you apply the exact same style to two elements - i.e. set _all_ existing properties to the same value - then shouldn't they look the same and align in the same way? I still think this is true - but only if you use "unambiguous" values for all the settings. The problem is with settings that have "ambiguous" values. If you use unambiguous values instead, you can in fact achieve the same look with the _same_ class. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found the answer myself:

I noticed that after adding `vertical-align: middle;` and `line-height: 2em;` to the `btn` class, the links and anchors will look exactly the same. You can then also remove the `overflow: hidden`.

The default values for these properties are `vertical-align: baseline;` and `line-height: normal;` - when you add these properties, the differences are still visible.

So I guess the deeper reason for this puzzle is a flaw in my underlying assumption that if the computed style properties, as shown in the developer tools, are the same, then two elements should also look the same. However, obviously there are settings with values like `vertical-align: baseline;` and `line-height: normal;` which do not have unambiguous meanings, instead they can have different meanings for different kinds of tags: E.g., where the baseline is and what a "normal" line height is, is defined differently for button and anchor tags.